# JSONArray to comma seperated String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a below JSON

```
{
    "id": 1111,
    "numbers": [
        "00",
        "01",
        "02"
    ],
    "alphabets": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

I want to convert this JSON array to string in JAVASCRIPT

Expected output:

```
{
    "id": 1111,
    "numbers": "00,01,02",
    "alphabets": "a,b,c"
}
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method should help you with that:

```js
["1", "2", "3"].join(',') // "1,2,3"
```

Assuming you don't want to modify the original object, you could start from something like this:

```js
const data = {
    "id": 1111,
    "numbers": [
        "00",
        "01",
        "02"
    ],
    "alphabets": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}

const modifiedData = {
    id: data.id,
    numbers: data.numbers.join(','),
    alphabets: data.alphabets.join(',')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries`, checking if value is an array and joining, then convert it back to object using `Object.fromEntries`, something like:

```js
const data = {
  "id": 1111,
  "numbers": [
    "00",
    "01",
    "02"
  ],
  "alphabets": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]
};

const result = Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [k, Array.isArray(v) ? v.join() : v]);

console.log(Object.fromEntries(result));
```